# Accidently formated my external 1TB hard drive!

Tags: data-recovery

Is there any way to recover the data off of my 1TB hard drive once it has been erased? From my mac I just selected that external drive and clicked on erase and both the partions are gone now :(

PS: I havn't copied anything on it.

Comment: Was there information/data on the drive before you erased it, that you are trying to recover?

Comment: @Stephen It was video tutorials etc. Some where around 700GB of video tutorials related to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 2 options at this point, #1 is to try a data recovery program and #2 is to have your hard drive sent in to a professional data recovery lab where they actually physically recover the data from the drive, but this can cost $1,000s. I have lost many many hard drives do to corruption and accidentally erasing and the best option for me has been to use [Data Rescue](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php). I actually just got done recovering over a TB worth of photos and videos from one of my hard drives and data rescue works wonderfully. I have tried many other data recovery applications and none of them work as well as this one. I hope this helps.

Comment: A simple question: Will it retain the folder structure? Cause series are like video 1 video 2. If its restoring the files only without structure then its waste.

Comment: @MohitJain From my experiences, you should be happy if you get most of the data unstructured back.

Comment: In most cases it does retain the file structure. The only time I have had problems with the file structure is if the hard drive has actually been corrupted or is damaged. You can try Data Rescue for free and see what it will do for you before you commit to buy it. http://www.prosofteng.com/downloads/download.php?prodID=78